# stream existing aac streams into browser using soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, browser, stream, aac

Is there any viable way to play streaming aac broadcasts in a web browser? (specifically on a wii)
I've already looked into flash and the VLCJ library with no luck.
I know I've been to at least one site that usually plays their stream from in-browser but I seem to recall it not working on the wii browser.

Thanks

Update:
I found a great js tool called sound manager 2 which claims to be able to do this, but can't get any AAC format streams to play. They are supposedly supported though. It makes me wonder if I'm configuring it wrong.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

```
<html>
<head><title>Radio Stations</title></head>
<!-- include SM2 library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="soundmanager2.js"></script>
<!-- configure it for your use -->
<script type="text/javascript">

soundManager.url = 'sm2-flash-files/';

soundManager.debugMode = true;
soundManager.preferFlash = true;
soundManager.useFlashBlock = true;
soundManager.flashVersion = 9;
soundManager.useHighPerformance = true; 
soundManager.useFastPolling = true; 

soundManager.onready(function(){

  var bleh = soundManager.createSound({
   id: 'NoLife-Radio',
   url: 'http://radio.nolife-radio.com:8000',
   type: 'audio/aac', // 'audio/mp4' ?
   autoPlay: false,
   stream: true,
   autoLoad: true
  });
});

soundManager.ontimeout(function(){

  // Hrmm, SM2 could not start. Flash blocker involved? Show an error, etc.?
  alert("Could not start");
});

</script>


<body>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript: soundManager.play('NoLife-Radio');">Play</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For playing streams put **;** at the end of the url, that will make it play.
So replace this:
`url: 'http://radio.nolife-radio.com:8000',`
with this `url: 'http://radio.nolife-radio.com:8000;',`

Regarding the format, play the stream in a player like Winamp and find out what is the correct format. Also you might want to put `soundManager.preferFlash = false;` so that browsers that can play sound using HTML5 audio api can use it instead of flash.